# Projected Based Document Root

Tags: apache2

I am trying to keep my `www` folder organized by having a folder for each project i.e:

```
www/project1
www/project2
```

However this is breaking my css links and script links because the files are being looked for in the wrong place. For example if I try to include `css/style.css` in project1 I would add the following markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

However Apache is looking in `www/css/style.css` instead of at the project's root, `www/project1/css/style.css`.

I know I could just use an absolute path but this means I would have to change all the URIs before deploying the code which is error-prone to say the least.

Is there a way I can teach apache to look in the Project's folder instead of the absolute root?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Apache virtual host similar to the following

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sandbox.lerp.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/sandbox
        <Directory /var/www/sandbox>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All
          </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in `/var/www/sandbox`, I have the following directory structure

[image]

Then your CSS link will work. Change `/var/www/sandbox` to reflect your document root. I generally use a different domain for each project with different virtual hosts. But I also have a sandbox where I keep multiple projects similar to your requirement.